# Trouble with numerically solving this system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I can numerically solve this system using ode45 (as i understand this is very similar to  the runge kutta 4th order method) in matlab no problem:

$x_1'=x_2-x_1^3+3x_1^2-x_3-3.25$

$x_2'=1-5x_1^2-x_2$

$x_3'=\frac{(4(x_1+1.6)-x_3)}{200}$

With initial conditions $x_1=-1.31, x_2=-7.32, x_3=3.35$.

However when adding the fourth equation:

$x_4'=\frac{x_2'x_1-x_1'x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$

ode45 does not give me the correct solution. The fourth equation has derivatives $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ and I am unsure if I need to make a transformation in order to solve, or use a different method entirely.

Comment: Did you substitute $x_1'$ and $x_2'$ into your equation for $x_4'$? 
 In other words, let $x_4'=\frac{(1-5x_1^2-x_2)x_1- (x_2-x_1^3+3x_1^2-x_3-3.25)x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$?

Comment: this was my first thought, but it does not give the expected result

Answer (score 2):

ode45 is a Runge-Kutta embedded method.
Since you have the explicit value of $x_1'$ and $ x_2 '$ you just need to put them in $x_4'$. Once you've found the initial condition for $x_4$, your system becomes:

$$\begin{cases}
x_1'=\dots \\
x_2'=\dots \\
x_3'=\dots \\
x_4'=\frac{(1-5x_1^2-x_2)x_1- (x_2-x_1^3+3x_1^2-x_3-3.25)x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \\
\vec{x(0)}= [-1.31,-7.32,3.35,x_4(0)]^T
\end{cases}$$

A numerical computation of the system, using $x_4(0)=-0.85$, using ode45 in MatLab gives the following numerical solution
[image: Plot of the solution]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this looks promising. Is there any chance you could send me the code you used?

Comment: I can't see the difficult in writing this code: if your code worked for the system with three equations, you just have to add one equation to your system with the respective initial condition. I just used the MatLab odesolver ode45. Anyway, how can I send you the code?

Comment: If you think that my post has answered to your questions, please mark it as accepted answer